# Query performance issues after using IS NULL condition in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, notin

I am using MySQL. I have a query as shown below :-

```
Select col1,col2,col3...,coln from table a 
left join table b ON a.id = b.id
left join table c on a.id = c.id
where a.id NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

Above query worked perfectly fine returning results in 5 seconds. It did not return any results for which a.id is NULL
I also wanted to include rows who have a.id is null. So I updated my query to include that

```
Select col1,col2,col3...,coln from table a 
left join table b ON a.id = b.id
left join table c on a.id = c.id
where a.id NOT IN (1,2,3) or a.id is NULL
```

But I guess, I am doing something wrong as query is running for quite a long time and then I am breaking the query.

Could any body please let me know why is there sudden decrease in performance?

I guess it is because of adding a.id is NULL, If that is the case, how can I include that in my condition to not affect performance.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Not sure if relevant, but, in MYSQL output window, when I run this query, DUration/Fetch shows as .050 sec/ ?

Meaning Duration is just .05 sec but fetch is what is taking the long time.

Comment: How many records we talking about here? with or condition and without or condition?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` for query tuning.

Comment: I do not have permissions to use "EXPLAIN"

Comment: There are around 200,000 records

Comment: Is `ID` indexed? What if you write it without `NOT IN`? `WHERE a.ID IS NULL OR a.ID<>1 OR a.ID<>2 OR a.ID<>3`.

Comment: You need to index id if not. Also you should not use IN as it will affect performcance. You can change like WHERE a.ID IS NULL OR a.ID!=1 AND a.ID!=2 AND a.ID!=3

Comment: a.id is defined as Primary key. So should not be a problem

Comment: How can the ID be NULL? It's the primary key!